# Removing a row from a datatable

Tags: vb.net, datatable

I have a program that asks the user a series of questions that are collected from a database and stored in a datatable.

I have a system that chooses two random numbers, one to determine which question and one to determine what order the answers are displayed. I want questions to remain in the datatable until the user gets it correct, and afterwards that question cannot come up again.

My datatable is called DT, and there's a line of code:

```
DT.Rows.RemoveAt(QNumber)
```

Which sounds like it should remove the row selected. However I have a question regarding this.

If for example QNumber was 2, and so row 2 was deleted. Would  this then move everything from row 3 in to row 2, and then everything from row 4 to row 3 and so on, or would this just make row 2 blank, and so break my code?

Comment: `Would this then move everything...` yes.  When 2 of 7 is removed there are now 6, but there is something different at index 2

Comment: @Plutonix Please provide an answer as an answer, not as a comment (otherwise someone else may take it, place it into an answer, and they'll get the rep).

Comment: gosh.  that would be horrible

Comment: @Plutonix You provided the answer to their question, it doesn't matter if it's short- provide a diagram if you have to (otherwise I'm going to take your answer for the benefit of other people who find this question).

Comment: @bob As per my little experience on SO, this site is to help others in complex matters and not primarily to gain rep.

Comment: @haraman It's *gamified*, reputation is a core model of the Stack Exchange network; it's how these sites work. I'm requesting that Plutonix needs to provide their answer *as an answer* in order to benefit others (and the OP) that find this question.

Comment: I can see where Bob is coming from as if provided as an answer I am able to mark the question as answered. However Plutonix got the point across nicely and briefly, thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't post any context are some test snippets:

Button1_Click loads a table

Button2_Click "processes" each row and optionally deletes the row.

In your case "process" would mean: display the question and loop until you get an answer.

In your case Button2 code would determine which record to load, probably using .Select() on the datatable that returns the "question" to ask, and eventually delete.

```
Dim da As SqlDataAdapter
Dim ds As DataSet
Dim dt As DataTable
Dim con As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection()

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Try
        Using con As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection()
            con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=APCD03;Initial Catalog=OIStest;Integrated Security=True"
            Dim rdr As Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader
            con.Open()
            Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT  [DBLinked] as PK ,[TEBackupDate] FROM [OISTest].[dbo].[_DBLink]", con)
            rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
            dt = New DataTable
            dt.Load(rdr)
            rdr.Close()
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex, ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
        If Not row.RowState = DataRowState.Deleted Then
            If MsgBox("Delete this row, PK: " & row("PK"), vbYesNo) = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
                row.Delete()
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Button3 demos selecting a specific row to process and delete:

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Dim rows() As DataRow = dt.Select("PK='test row'")
    If rows.Length = 0 Then
        MsgBox("row was deleted already")
    Else
        MsgBox(rows(0)(0)) ' display PK
        If MsgBox("Delete " & rows(0)(0), vbYesNo) = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
            rows(0).Delete()
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Note that `rows(0)` is the first record of the result from the select - not the record index in the overall table.

Comment: There'd not really be an easy way for me to show you my code unless I edit it on to the end of my post, or put it on to pastebin. I can do either of those if you want though. I was only asking about the specific function so I didn't feel it needed examples. Thanks  for the lengthy reply though, it's interesting to read as this is all completely different to how I did it. Even how you filled the datatable with dt.load, that's not how I did it. Perhaps I should show you my code and you could tell me how/if I could improve it?

Comment: My code to fill a DT is usually wrapped in a Function() that returns a datatable - I just pass in the SQL. This makes it easy to get a table. I have similar Functions for Scalars, Dataviews, and other common ADO.Net tasks. This is quite different from bound controls. I just happen to have some spare time for the long reply - not really looking for code review tasks. If you have sticking points feel free to post code.

Comment: I usually put- DT = RunSQL(SQL) with RunSQL being a function that returns a database and then SQL being a string. One line of your code I was particularly curious about was in the very last snippet. What's "vbYesNo"? It sounds like it gives a messagebox with a yes or no option instead of just an OK button? This sounds like something I need for confirming deleting something elsewhere in the code

Comment: The second parameter determines which buttons appear, which is the default, and the icon displayed. I cheated and used the brief contstant which works in some cases. The proper syntax would have been like this: `IF MsgBox("row was deleted already", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo + MsgBoxStyle.DefaultButton2 + MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation ) THEN`  which would show two buttons with No as the default and an Exclamation mark icon.

Comment: FYI MsgBox() is in the Visual.Basic namespace for WinForms (and VBA.) Other environs use other objects. MessageBox is available across more platforms but is inconsistent from one to another. MsgBox is the simplest, MessageBox() supports more stuff - like help files. You can mix and match as needed.

Comment: So if I wanted the two buttons to be No and Yes with no being default, instead of being no and !, would I change MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation?

Comment: Yes - just delete ` + MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation'